# How should I configure my service to access grafana with : localhost:3000 with minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have deployed grafana in minikube, but can't access it on url : `127.0.0.1:3000`

Here is my service file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grafana-local
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: grafana-local
    component: core
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3000
  selector:
    app: grafana-local
    component: core
```

When I do `minikube service list`, I get this:

```
| monitoring           | grafana-local             |            3000 | http://172.17.0.3:32113 |
```

When I acces grafana via `http://172.17.0.3:32113`, it is working. But wasn't it supposed to forward it to port 3000 on host with section:

```
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3000
```

???

Comment: I would like to suggest this [article](https://medium.com/faun/trying-prometheus-operator-with-helm-minikube-b617a2dccfa3), I used it a time ago to configure grafana's dashboard. however, you will need to use helm to deploy things out.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different port configurations for Kubernetes services:

- `Port` exposes the Kubernetes service on the specified port **within the cluster**. Other pods within the cluster can communicate with this server on the specified port.
- `TargetPort` is the port on which the service will send requests to, that your pod will be listening on. Your application in the container will need to be listening on this port also.
- `NodePort` **exposes a service externally** to the cluster by means of the target nodes IP address and the `NodePort`. `NodePort` is the default setting if the port field is not specified.

From your example above the `grafana-local` service will be exposed internally to cluster applications on port 3000 and externally to the cluster on the node IP address on 32113. The `NodePort` was not specified by your config so it was allocated to 32113 from the predefined `NodePort` default range of 30000-32767.

You can check the details of your service with:

```
kubectl describe service grafana-local
```

If you want to change your `NodePort` to value different from the default range of 30000-32767 you need to update the file `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` and add the line `--service-node-port-range=xxx-yyy` (pick your values here). As the directory is monitored by `kubelet` for any changes, there is no need to do anything more. The `kube-apiserver` will be recreated with the new settings. Remember however that the default range was picked for a reason to avoid network conflicts so you need to make sure it won't override other ports that you want to use in your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Well whatever you configured seem correct to me.  if you want to access on localhost:3000 then do a port forward using

```
kubectl port-forward pod_name 3000:3000
```

Then go to `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: this works, but is there a way to put it in a config file ? I have like 10 services, and don't want to execute 10 times this command for each local service.

Answer (score -1):

Try with your host name/IP and NodePort.

```
http://<host IP>:3000
```

Comment: That is not what I want, I already said in question, with `http://172.17.0.3:32113` it is working

Comment: I meant to say NodePort with host IP